# Nested Prolog functions

Tags: prolog

```
rotate(X):-
write('convert -rotate 90 '),write(X),write(' o.jpg'),
writeln(0).
beside(X,Y):-
write('convert -scale 50%%x50%% '),write(X),writeln(' 0111.jpg'),
write('convert -scale 50%%x50%% '),write(Y),writeln(' 01121.jpg'),
write('convert +append '),write(X),write(Y),writeln(' o.jpg').
```

above are my prolog codes for rotate and beside functions. How can i modify the codes to suit case like rotate(beside(X,Y)). which are nested

Answer (score 3):

You can't. That's because `rotate` and `beside` are not functions, they are predicates.

Functions return values and so you nest them – use the return value of one function as an input of another function. On the other hand, when you try to evaluate a predicate in Prolog, it tries to “unify” all its unbound parameters using the rules you gave it, and returns whether that succeeded and how.

Code like `rotate(beside(X,Y)).` is valued, but it doesn't mean what you think. It tries to evaluate the predicate `rotate` on a structure `beside(X,Y)`. It doesn't try to evaluate the `beside` predicate.

Comment: It is possible to implement [lambda expressions in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56666729/975097), which can be used like anonymous functions.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are trying to use these like functions.  The Prolog way is more like this:

```
rotate(X,Output):-
write('convert -rotate 90 '),write(X),write(' o.jpg'),
writeln(0),Output='o.jpg'.
beside(X,Y,Output):-
write('convert -scale 50%%x50%% '),write(X),writeln(' 0111.jpg'),
write('convert -scale 50%%x50%% '),write(Y),writeln(' 01121.jpg'),
write('convert +append '),write(X),write(Y),writeln(' o.jpg'),Output='o.jpg'.
```

then use

```
beside(X,Y,Temp),rotate(Temp,Output).
```