# How to take procedure as input in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am doing a assignment in Prolog. I want to give some procedure as input instead of writing them in code.

For example, currently:

My code is:

```
friends(aa,bb).
friends(bb,cc).
abc(X, Y) :-
    friends(X,Y).
```

and my input command is

```
abc(aa,Y).
```

and output is

```
Y = bb
```

....

BUt I want my code to be this

```
abc(X, Y) :-
    friends(X,Y).
```

and some how give the `friends` procedure as input and get the same output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `call` for this:

```
friends(aa, bb).
friends(bb, cc).

indirect_abc(Goal_2, X, Y) :-
    call(Goal_2, X, Y).
```

Test:

```
?- indirect_abc(friends, X, Y).
X = aa,
Y = bb ;
X = bb,
Y = cc.

?- indirect_abc(friends, aa, Y).
Y = bb.
```

**Edit:** Following a comment below, the variable name `Goal_2` could be read as "a term that needs two arguments to become a goal". `call` supplies those arguments and calls the resulting goal.

Comment: `Goal` is not a goal. It is a goal lacking two arguments. Thus `Goal_2` might be a better name.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the name. I'm not 100% sure this is the best name, but I agree that it's a good idea to make this explicit somehow.

Comment: So far, using a suffix like `_2` has not been used for anything in Prolog. [Systems use](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/conformity_testing#227) that suffix alone for naming otherwise unnamed variables.  Directly adding a number rather refers to different places of difference lists and accumulators. I am very much tempted to type such arguments.

Comment: I want to tell the program, `aa` is friend of `bb` and `bb` is friend of `cc` in the input.

Comment: but in your example, that is included in the program itself

Comment: The short answer is that Prolog is not very well suited for this kind of thing. If the data is expected to by dynamic, and it's only pairs, how about passing a list of pairs and searching that list? But more generally, some Prologs come with libraries for "anonymous predicates": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56662067/is-there-something-like-anonymous-predicates-in-swi-prolog